# List of Todos in Beamer

Tags: beamer, todonotes

In the following MWE, I am trying to put the first frame as a list of todos over the whole presentation. However, I got an error

> Undefined control sequence. \contentsline

So, what is wrong in this code?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{List of Todos}
    \listoftodos
\end{frame}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
    \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
    \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
    \todo[inline]{1st ToDo}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
    \todo[inline]{2nd ToDo}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like `\listoftodos` is incompatible with beamer. [Source](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/metropolis-beamer-theme/qzyvdhrntfmr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need all the features from `todonotes` you can simply implement some basic functionalities yourself:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcounter{todo}
\newtcbox{\mytodobox}{colback=orange,colframe=orange!75!black}

\newcommand\todo[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{todo} 
    \mytodobox{\hypertarget{todo\thetodo}{#1}}
    \addcontentsline{tod}{subsection}{\protect\hyperlink{todo\thetodo}{\thetodo~#1}\par} 
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listoftodos{%
    \@starttoc{tod}}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{List of Todos}
        \listoftodos
    \end{frame}

    \maketitle

    \begin{frame}{Table of contents}
        \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
        \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{frame}
        \todo{1nd ToDo}
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section 2}
    \begin{frame}
        \todo{2nd ToDo}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Is it possible to make the entries in this list hyperlinks (without color or frame around them) to the respective todos?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Sorry, but I am unable to do so. I tried `\newcommand\todo[1]{%
 \refstepcounter{todo}
 \mytodobox{\hypertarget{todo\thetodo}{#1}}
 \addcontentsline{tod}{subsection}{\hyperlink{todo\thetodo}{\thetodo~#1}\par}
}%` but this just generates a bunch of errors.... too late at night to  think about that.

Comment: I highly appreciate your willingness to help.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou See the edit, its now clickable :) a simple `\protect` was missing.

Comment: @samcarter: Explicit `\hyperlinks` in `\addcontentsline` always require a `\protect`.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for satisfying my greediness :)

Comment: @DiaaAbidou You're welcome!

Comment: Im downvoting the answer because it doesn't solve the original problem.